# Separate configuration file for MS Enterprise Library

Tags: enterprise-library

I have a section on my ASP.net web.config for the Enterprise library logging block. Is it possible to separate the logging configuration into another configuration file? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible -- in fact, separate config files for each app block was the only way that Enterprise Library 1.0 worked.

Check out [this blog post](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/EnterpriseLibraryConfigurationSeparateConfigurationFilesApplicationBlocks.aspx) from David Hayden -- he shows how to set up the configs for each application block in separate files.

Answer (score 2):

Any section in the Web.config can live outside of the Web.config. Just add a [configSource attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) and specify the filename. Here is an example of what we did for one project.

```
<configuration>
  <configSection>
    <section name="microMvc" type="MicroMvc.MvcSection" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
  </configSection>
  <microMvc configSource="micromvc.config" />
</configuration>
```